# A convex quadrilateral with sides $a$, $b$, $c$ has maximal area when its fourth side satisfies $x^3-(a^2+b^2+c^2)x-2abc=0$

Tags: euclidean-geometry, quadrilateral

> Three sides of a convex quadrilateral $ABCD$ have lengths $AB = a$, $BC = b$, and $CD = c$. If the area of ​​the quadrilateral is as large as possible, prove that the length $x$ of the fourth side satisfies the equation
> $$x^3-(a^2+b^2+c^2)x-2abc=0$$

I know a solution by calculus, but I want to know if there is a solution by euclidean geometry and factorization (without derivatives).

Thanks for attention.

The calculus solution

$$d^2=a^2+b^2-2ab\cos(\theta)\\
Area=\frac{cd}{2}\sin\alpha+\frac{ab}{2}\sin(\theta)\\
d^2=x^2-c^2\\
x^2-c^2=a^2+b^2-2ab\cos(\theta)\\
\sin\theta=\frac{\sqrt{4a^2b^2-(x^2-a^2-b^2-c^2)^2}}{2ab}\\ 
Area=\frac{c.\sqrt{x^2-c^2}}{2}+\frac{ab}{2}.\frac{\sqrt{4a^2b^2-(x^2-a^2-b^2-c^2)^2}}{2ab}\\
Area=\frac{c.\sqrt{x^2-c^2}}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{4a^2b^2-(x^2-a^2-b^2-c^2)^2}}{4}
$$

Doing $\frac{d}{dx}$

$$
\frac{2xc}{4\sqrt{x^2-c^2}}-\frac{2(x^2-a^2-b^2-c^2).2x}{8\sqrt{4a^2b^2-(x^2-a^2-b^2-c^2)^2}}=0\\
\frac{c}{\sqrt{x^2-c^2}}=\frac{(x^2-a^2-b^2-c^2)}{\sqrt{4a^2b^2-(x^2-a^2-b^2-c^2)^2}}\\
c\sqrt{4a^2b^2-(x^2-a^2-b^2-c^2)^2}=(x^2-a^2-b^2-c^2)\sqrt{x^2-c^2}\\
4a^2b^2.c^2-c^2.(x^2-a^2-b^2-c^2)^2=(x^2-a^2-b^2-c^2)^2(x^2-c^2)\\
4a^2b^2c^2=(x^2-a^2-b^2-c^2)^2.x^2\\
2abc=(x^2-a^2-b^2-c^2).x\\
x^3-(a^2+b^2+c^2)x-2abc=0
$$

Comment: Is this a contest problem?  Please, in any case, cite the source of the problem.

Comment: I don't know. This is in my book.

Comment: Calculus is  best suited for such max/min problems. Please show the calculus solution at least, as effort by you so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the positions of sides $a$ and $b$ are fixed, maximum area is achieved when side $c$ is perpendicular diagonal $AC$. Analogously, if the positions of sides $b$ and $c$ are fixed, maximum area is achieved when side $a$ is perpendicular to diagonal $BD$. It follows that we have maximum area when $\angle ABD=\angle ACD=90°$, that is when quadrilateral $ABCD$ is inscribed in a half-circle of diameter $AD=x$.

To find $x$, let $2\alpha$, $2\beta$ and $2\gamma$ be the central angles subtending $a$, $b$ and $c$ respectively. We have then:
$$
x={a\over\sin\alpha}={b\over\sin\beta}={c\over\sin\gamma}.
$$
From the first equality we get $\sin\beta=(b/a)\sin\alpha$. From the second equality, taking into account that $\alpha+\beta+\gamma=90°$ and
$\sin\gamma=\cos(\alpha+\beta)=\cos\alpha\cos\beta-\sin\alpha\sin\beta$, we have:
$$
a(\cos\alpha\cos\beta-\sin\alpha\sin\beta)=c\sin\alpha,
$$
that is:
$$
a\sqrt{1-\sin^2\alpha}\sqrt{1-(b/a)^2\sin^2\alpha}=c\sin\alpha+b\sin^2\alpha.
$$
Squaring both sides and rearranging we finally obtain:
$$
a^2=(a^2+b^2+c^2)\sin^2\alpha+2bc\sin^3\alpha.
$$
Substituting there $\sin\alpha=a/x$ gives then the requested equality.

[image]